# Pygooglevoice TypeError: get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'raw'

Tags: python, typeerror, google-voice, raw

I am trying to send SMS messages with the pygooglevoice package. I followed the installation instructions on their website http://sphinxdoc.github.io/pygooglevoice/index.html (except that I installed the package with pip and not easy_install). Then I set up the account/password document and used the following code provided on http://sphinxdoc.github.io/pygooglevoice/examples.html#send-sms-messages to send SMS messages.

However, I am getting a TypeError saying that there is an unexpected argument named "raw" in a document called configparser.py. Can anyone kindly help interpret this error message below & suggest possible solutions? Much thanks!

````
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-75-590efd152ee6> in <module>
      3 
      4 voice = Voice()
----> 5 voice.login()
      6 
      7 phoneNumber = input('4437348572')

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/googlevoice/voice.py in login(self, email, passwd)
     58 
     59         if email is None:
---> 60             email = config.email
     61         if email is None:
     62             email = input('Email address: ')

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/googlevoice/conf.py in <lambda>(self)
     53     phoneType = property(phoneType)
     54     forwardingNumber = property(lambda self: self.get('forwardingNumber'))
---> 55     email = property(lambda self: self.get('email', 'auth'))
     56     password = property(lambda self: self.get('password', 'auth'))
     57     secret = property(lambda self: self.get('secret'))

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/googlevoice/conf.py in get(self, option, section)
     33     def get(self, option, section='gvoice'):
     34         try:
---> 35             return ConfigParser.get(self, section, option).strip() or None
     36         except NoOptionError:
     37             return

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/configparser.py in get(self, section, option, raw, vars, fallback)
    797             return value
    798         else:
--> 799             return self._interpolation.before_get(self, section, option, value,
    800                                                   d)
    801 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/configparser.py in before_get(self, parser, section, option, value, defaults)
    393     def before_get(self, parser, section, option, value, defaults):
    394         L = []
--> 395         self._interpolate_some(parser, option, L, value, section, defaults, 1)
    396         return ''.join(L)
    397 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/configparser.py in _interpolate_some(self, parser, option, accum, rest, section, map, depth)
    406     def _interpolate_some(self, parser, option, accum, rest, section, map,
    407                           depth):
--> 408         rawval = parser.get(section, option, raw=True, fallback=rest)
    409         if depth > MAX_INTERPOLATION_DEPTH:
    410             raise InterpolationDepthError(option, section, rawval)

TypeError: get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'raw'```
````

Comment: Are you using a version of pygooglevoice older than Sep 2016? I ran into this same error message while porting another project from 2 to 3, but it looks like the pygooglevoice github fixed the issue on Oct 29, 2016.